# python PILL generate image from text colors problem

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library, drop

i have problem with my code i want to make class that manage image text, i added params but whatever i used as style it does not applied like text colors borders shadows etc etc
hope any one can give the any idea
here is what i tried

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

class ImageEditor:
    def __init__(self, width, height, background_color):
        self.image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color=background_color)
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

    def import_image(self, filename):
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            raise FileNotFoundError("File not found!")
        self.image = Image.open(filename)
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

    def add_text(self, text, direction, text_color, font_size, font_path, border, border_color, shadow_color, x, y, bg_color):
        font_file = None
        font_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'Fonts')
        found = False
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(font_dir, font_path)):
            font_path = os.path.join(font_dir, font_path)
            found = True
        else:
            found = False
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
                for filename in filenames:
                    if filename.lower() == font_path.lower():
                        font_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                        print(font_path)
                        found = True
                        break
                if found:
                    break
            else:
                found = False

        if not found:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Font file '{font_path}' not found!")



        # Define the font
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)

        # Determine the text size
        bbox = self.draw.textbbox((x, y), text, font=font)
        text_width = bbox[2] - bbox[0]
        text_height = bbox[3] - bbox[1]

        # Define the coordinates for the text
        if direction == "ltr":
            x_start = x
            y_start = y
            text_direction = "ltr"
        elif direction == "rtl":
            x_start = x - text_width
            y_start = y
            text_direction = "rtl"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid direction value! Allowed values: 'ltr' or 'rtl'.")

        # Add the text shadow
        shadow_offset = (border[0]/2, border[1]/2)
        shadow_position = (x_start + shadow_offset[0], y_start + shadow_offset[1])
        try:
            self.draw.text(shadow_position, text, font=font, fill=shadow_color, direction=text_direction)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Error adding text shadow!") from e

        # Add the text border
        border_offset = (border[0]/2, border[1]/2)
        for x_offset in range(-round(border_offset[0]), round(border_offset[0]) + 1):
            for y_offset in range(-round(border_offset[1]), round(border_offset[1]) + 1):
                position = (x_start + x_offset, y_start + y_offset)
                try:
                    self.draw.text(position, text, font=font, fill=border_color, direction=text_direction)
                except Exception as e:
                    raise RuntimeError("Error adding text border!") from e

        text_position = (x_start, y_start)
        try:
            self.draw.text(text_position, text, font=font, fill=bg_color, direction=text_direction)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Error adding text!") from e

        # Add the text
        text_position = (x_start, y_start)
        try:
            self.draw.text(text_position, text, font=font, fill=text_color, direction=text_direction)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Error adding text!") from e

    def export_image(self, filename):
        try:
            self.image.save(filename)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Error exporting image!") from e

    def get_image_info(self):
        info_dict = {}

        info_dict["filename"] = self.image.filename if hasattr(self.image, 'filename') else ""
        info_dict["format"] = self.image.format if hasattr(self.image, 'format') else ""
        info_dict["size"] = self.image.size if hasattr(self.image, 'size') else ""
        info_dict["mode"] = self.image.mode if hasattr(self.image, 'mode') else ""
        info_dict["dpi"] = self.image.info.get("dpi", None) if hasattr(self.image, 'info') else None
        info_dict["description"] = self.image.info.get("description", None) if hasattr(self.image, 'info') else None
    
        return info_dict


# Create an instance of the ImageEditor class with a white background (A4 size at 300 DPI)
editor = ImageEditor(2480, 3508, (255, 255, 255))

# Add Arabic text with a shadow and border
arabic_text = "تجربة نص عربي طويل"
border_color = (0, 0, 255)
text_color = (255, 0, 0)
shadow_color = (100, 100, 100)
font_path = "arial.ttf"
font_size = 48
border = (10, 10)
x = 500
y = 500
direction = "rtl"
editor.add_text(arabic_text, direction, text_color, font_size, font_path, border, border_color, shadow_color, x, y, (255, 255, 255))

# Add English text with a border and a different font
english_text = "This is a long English text."
border_color = (255, 0, 0)
text_color = (0, 0, 255)
shadow_color = (100, 100, 100)
font_path = "times.ttf"
font_size = 36
border = (5, 5)
x = 1000
y = 800
direction = "ltr"
editor.add_text(english_text, direction, text_color, font_size, font_path, border, border_color, shadow_color, x, y, (255, 255, 255))

# Add French text with a background color and a different font
french_text = "Voici un long texte français."
background_color = (255, 255, 0)
text_color = (0, 255, 0)
shadow_color = (100, 100, 100)
font_path = "times.ttf"
font_size = 24
border = (0, 0)
x = 600
y = 1500
direction = "ltr"
editor.add_text(french_text, direction, text_color, font_size, font_path, border, background_color, shadow_color, x, y, (255, 255, 255))

# Add German text with a border, background color, and a different font
german_text = "Das ist ein langer deutscher Text."
background_color = (0, 255, 255)
text_color = (255, 0, 255)
shadow_color = (100, 100, 100)
font_path = "arial.ttf"
font_size = 28
border = (10, 10)
x = 1200
y = 1700
direction = "ltr"
editor.add_text(german_text, direction, text_color, font_size, font_path, border, border_color, shadow_color, x, y, background_color)

# Add Spanish text with a border, background color, and a different font
spanish_text = "Este es un texto español largo."
background_color = (255, 128, 0)
text_color = (0, 255, 255)
shadow_color = (100, 100, 100)
font_path = "arial.ttf"
font_size = 32
border = (5, 5)
x = 800
y = 2300
direction = "ltr"
editor.add_text(spanish_text, direction, text_color, font_size, font_path, border, border_color, shadow_color, x, y, background_color)

# Export the final image to a file
editor.export_image("final_image.jpg")
print(editor.get_image_info())
```

here is the result i got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYkhE.jpg)

normally it should give the colors but it didn't